# Is it possible to get collection of some ejb`s instances from container?

Tags: java, glassfish, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1, glassfish-3

**Scenario:** I have some `@Statefull` bean for user session (not an HTTP session, it is web services session). And I need to manage user's session per user.

**Goal:** I need to have possibility to get collection of `@Statefull UserSession` instances and control maximum number of session`s per user, and session`s life time.

**Question:** Is it possible to get Collection of EJB instances from EJB container, instead of storing them in some collection, map, etc?

I am using GlassFish v3, EJB 3.1, JAX-WS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is not possible..